# como puedo hacer para que estos tres metodos se puedan ejecutar en uno solo, metodo depthFirstForEch y recorra de las tres maneras

Tags: javascript, json

// corre depth-first (en recorrido "in-order") cuando depthFirstForEach() es ejecutado sin ninguna opcion o con la opcion "in-order

// corre depth-first (en recorrido "pre-order") cuando depthFirstForEach() es ejecutado con la opcion "pre-order"

// corre depth-first (en recorrido "post-order" cuando depthFirstForEach() es ejecutado con la opcion "post-order

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.inOrderTraversal = function(fn) {
  if (!this.left && !this.right) return fn(this.value) 
  if(!!this.left) this.left.inOrderTraversal(fn)
  fn(this.value) // print parent node after all its left nodes returned 
  if(!!this.right) this.right.inOrderTraversal(fn)
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.preOrderTraversal = function(fn) {
  fn(this.value) // print parent node
  if(!!this.left) this.left.preOrderTraversal(fn) 
  if(!!this.right) this.right.preOrderTraversal(fn) 
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.postOrderTraversal = function(fn) {
  if(!!this.left) this.left.preOrderTraversal(fn)
  if(!!this.right) this.right.preOrderTraversal(fn)
  fn(this.value) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitarías agregar un método y comparar los valores de una opción pasada por el método y suponiendo que la función que utilizas como `callback` en cada uno de los métodos con los que recorres el árbol está definida

```
function testFn(value) {
    console.log(value)
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.depthFirstForEach = function(option) {
    if (!option) {
        this.inOrderTraversal(testFn)
    }

    if (option === 'pre-order') {
        this.preOrderTraversal(testFn)
    }

    if (option === 'post-order') {
        this.postOrderTraversal(testFn);
    }
}
```

En caso que necesites pasar la función callback como argumento lo puedes añadir en la definición de la función `depthFirstForEach`